# How can i create this advanced shape in CSS?

Tags: css, animation, svg

I want to create the same ***orange*** shape in the example below using pure CSS or any tool, I've tried clip-path and some SVG generators, but i couldn't do it.

Please help !!

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcKCo.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51086332/8620333

Comment: please describe what you've done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of an SVG Path with the shape:

```html
<svg width="300" height="200">
  <path d="M 0,0 H 180 Q 200,0 210,17.32 
  L 280,138.56 Q 300,173.2 270,173.2 H 0 V 0 Z" fill="orange" stroke="none" />
</svg>
```